# Find Quantity of Biggest integers in N integers in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, int, stdio

I want to do this code that tells you the number of (n) integers that are bigger (or equal) than a (k) input.

So for example:

```
input:
4 15
12 
6 
15
24

output:
2
```

So the 4 is the number of integers the user is going to input and the 15 is the k number, now the output is the quantity of numbers that are bigger than k.

What I have of code is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, k, i;
    int c, d;     
    scanf(" %d",&n);
    scanf("%d", &k);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&c);
        if (c[i]>k)
            c[i]=d;
    }
    printf("%d", d);      
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see my code sucks, I don't know how to find the integers that are bigger than k and to print the quantity, not the numbers themselves. Any help is really appreaciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn how to indent code. Pick a coding style and stay with it

Comment: Yeah I edited it, it is bigger or equal to k

Comment: @JackWilliams I understand, but I am very new to this. :/

Comment: I get compiler errors when I try to compile this. Have you tried fixing those first?

Comment: @Evert To be fair, a post _or comment_ that says "I get errors" without listing any is not very useful.  Suggest listing at least one of the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are trying to reference `c` as an array.  That is not needed.  Try this:

```
int main() 
{
   int n, k, i, c;
   int count = 0;

   scanf(" %d",&n);
   scanf("%d", &k);

   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
     scanf("%d",&c);
     if (c > k)
       count++;
   }

   printf("%d", count); 
   return 0
}
```

Also, I would rename your variables to something more meaningful, such as `numEntries`, `checkValue`, etc.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. One question, how does count++ work on the code without using another for? Sorry if it is a stupid question, im just new to this. And thanks again.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  ++ is the auto-increment operator.  So it adds 1 to the existing value of count each time the condition ( c>k) is met.  Spend some time learning how to use a debugger, and step through the code to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Far less elegant solution, but one that keeps the value you need for some further use.. OldProgrammer did it much simpler and more pretty.

```
int main()
{   
  int num, s, i, cnt = 0;
  printf("please input number of integers and int to compare with\n");
  scanf("%d %d", &s, &num);
  int arr[s];
  for(i = 0; i < s; i++)
  {
    printf("Please input %d. number", i+1);  
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < s; i++)
  {
    if(arr[i] >= num)
      cnt++;
  }
   //at this point cnt holds the value you need

  return 0;
}
```